# Meizu M5s Android 6.0

Tags: android

Good day. I use the Meizu M5s Android 6.0 smartphone, I want to install Ubuntu, how can I do it?

Thank you in advance.
Funt Sem

Answer (score 2):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch

Ubuntu Touch (also known as Ubuntu Phone) is a mobile version of the Ubuntu operating system that was originally developed by Canonical Ltd. and is now being developed by the UBports community.

and https://ubports.com/

Find out how to install our latest version of the Ubuntu Touch operating system on your mobile device.